# Placing link in the middle (horizontally/vertically) inside the div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I need to center link inside the div vertically and horizontally.

My CSS:

```
    .div {
       display:block;
       background:red;
       width:162px;
       height:168px;
    }
    .span { }
    .link { }
```

My HTML:

```
    <div class="div">
       <span class="span">
          <a href="#" class="link"> Text in middle </a>
       </span>
    </div>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/pjWUC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the coding in your example, use:

[**Updated jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/pjWUC/1/) - `a` element is centered vertically and horizontally.

```
.div {
    display:table;
    background:red;
    width:162px;
    height:168px;
}
.span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: [It works in IE8, no lower.](http://caniuse.com/css-table) Do you need something that works in IE7?

Comment: Yes I would need IE7 support as well.
I believe it would be done with display: inline-block; ?

Is it ok to target IE7 and lower by adding * in front of css property?

Answer (score 0):

```
.div {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, display:table-cell is not supported by IE according to [this](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/properties/classify/display.htm).

Comment: Why not? You didn't specify any further requirements.

Comment: Because this will make text center horizontally but not vertically. Try it for yourself..

Comment: I apologize.  I left out the display: part and the browser compatibility information.  Edited.